# Header div not coming on top of content div

Tags: html, css

This is the jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/33vtLq3j/2/) to my HTML page, and its clear that there is space between the header and content divs and in between content and footer divs. What is causing this, how to remove this. What changes should I do in my CSS?

If I do margin-top:-50px in the content div then it touches the bottom of the header div? But this seems more of a hack and this does n't works with the footer? Moreover I don't like this approach.

**CSS**

```
 html{
   font-size:100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   min-height: 100%;
   position: relative;
 }
 body{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 }
 #header{
   background-color:#007FFF;
   width : 100%;
   height:130px;
 }
 #content{
   background-color:#B0E2FF;
   margin-bottom:0px;
   margin-top:0px;
 }
 #footer{
   background-color:#B0E2FF;
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 90px;
   width: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;    
 }
 h1 {
   font: bold italic 3em/1em "Times New Roman", "MS Serif", "New York", serif;
   padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0;
   color: #e7ce00;
}   

h2 {
   font: bold italic 2em/1em "Times New Roman", "MS Serif", "New York", serif;
   padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0;
   color: #e7ce00;
}

#wrapper{
   width:60%;
   margin:0 auto;
   background-color: red;
}

.scrollabletextbox{
   width:900px;
   height:120px;
   -webkit-border-radius:10px;
   -moz-border-radius:10px;
   border-radius:10px;
   border:3px solid #00008B;
   background-color:#E6E8FA;
}

#querytextarea{
  float: left;
}

button{
  float: right;
}

form:{
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h2>Console</h2>
       <h1>Query</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
     <div id="wrapper">
       <form>
          <h3 style="margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:50px; color:##22316C">Mongo Query</h3>
          <textarea id = "querytextarea" class="scrollabletextbox" name="MongoQuery" rows="20" cols="30"></textarea><br>
           <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
           <br>
          <h3 style="margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:10px; color:##22316C">Result</h3>
          <textarea class="scrollabletextbox" name="Result"  rows="20" cols="30"></textarea>
       </form>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Just remove `margin-top: 50px` of `h3`'s inline-style.

Answer (score 1):

You could exchange the `margin-top`of the `h3` inside the `#content` with `padding-top`

```
#content {
    h3 {
        margin: 0;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
}
```

Consider using classes for styling instead of an id.

Answer (score 1):

Give a padding of atleast `1px`

```
#content{
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Here is the **updated [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/33vtLq3j/8/)**

```css
          html{
   font-size:100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   min-height: 100%;
   position: relative;
 }
 body{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 }
 #header{
   background-color:#007FFF;
   width : 100%;
   height:130px;
 }
 #content{
   background-color:#B0E2FF;
   margin-bottom:0px;
   margin-top:0px;
 }
 #footer{
   background-color:green;
   position: fixed;
   left:0;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 90px;
   width: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;    
 }
 h1 {
   font: bold italic 3em/1em "Times New Roman", "MS Serif", "New York", serif;
   padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0;
   color: #e7ce00;
} 

h2 {
   font: bold italic 2em/1em "Times New Roman", "MS Serif", "New York", serif;
   padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0;
   color: #e7ce00;
}

#wrapper{
   width:60%;
   margin:0 auto;
   background-color: red;
}

  .scrollabletextbox{
   width:900px;
   height:120px;
   -webkit-border-radius:10px;
   -moz-border-radius:10px;
   border-radius:10px;
   border:3px solid #00008B;
   background-color:#E6E8FA;
}

#querytextarea{
  float: left;
}

button{
  float: right;
}

form:{
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#content{
    padding: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 100px; // since footer is having 90px height
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <div id="header">
     <h2>Console</h2>
    <h1>Query</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <form>
       <h3 style="margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:50px; color:##22316C">Mongo Query</h3>
    <textarea id = "querytextarea" class="scrollabletextbox" name="MongoQuery" rows="20" cols="30"></textarea><br>
     <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
     <br>
    <h3 style="margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:10px; color:##22316C">Result</h3>
    <textarea class="scrollabletextbox" name="Result"  rows="20" cols="30"></textarea>
    </form>
   </div> 
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
 </div>
 </body>
```

**EDIT**

To arrange footer

```
#content{
    padding: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 100px; // since footer is having 90px height
}
```

Here is the **updated [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/33vtLq3j/10/)**

Comment: But the bottom space betweent the bottom div and the footer stillremains

Comment: @JohnDoe Are you sure you want the position of footer to be `absolute`?

Comment: But I want the footer to stick to the bottom.

Comment: @JohnDoe okay. 1 sec then, Updated

Comment: @Shyam Pillai Not yet!!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you have set a margin-top (on HTML file) on your h3 element.

Juste change it like this :

```
<h3 style="margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:50px; color:##22316C">Mongo Query</h3>
```

But this should be better, on HTML :

```
<h3 id="myFirstH3">Mongo Query</h3>
```

And on CSS add this:

```
#myFirstH3{
    margin-bottom:1px;
    margin-top:0px; /*set to 0 because h3 have a margin top by default*/
    color:#22316C;
}
```

It's better to place css on CSS file.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**
Response too late ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove top margin from h3

```
<h3 style="margin-bottom:1px;margin-top:0px; color:#22316C">Mongo Query</h3>
```

**AND**

If you also wants to footer comes after content then remove bottom:0 from below css.

```
#footer{
background-color:#B0E2FF;
position: absolute;
left:0;
bottom: 0;
height: 90px;
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;    
}
```

Comment: But I want the footer to stick to the bottom.

Comment: then no need to remove that property from #footer